# scanimage and shell_exec ... Possible?

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

I have a problem with a script :

When I try to do `shell_exec("scanimage > /var/www/html/site/scans")` nothing happens.
But if I just do `echo shell_exec("scanimage -L")`, it returns the good result.
User www-data is well in the scanner group.

I don't understand anything !! Please help me.

EDIT :
I solved the solution by `usermod -aG www-data lp`, then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the backtick operator:

```
`scanimage > /var/www/html/site/scans`;
```

Comment: You can try storing the result of the command (using shell_exec) and then put it in the directory that you want.

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that you are sending the output to a directory, isn't that supposed to be a file instead? Try something like: shell_exec("scanimage > /var/www/html/site/scans/scan1");

Comment: Oh yes you're right ! That's a mistake I did on the post x) But not on my script ...
I try with $result = shell_exec("command");, but I don't even hear my scanner

Comment: Did you try something like this? $result = shell_exec("command"); file_put_contents('/var/www/html/site/scans/scan1', $result);

Comment: It doesn't work but I got an error :D
A permission problem : sh: 1: cannot create /var/www/html/Power-scan/scans/scan1.ppm: Permission denied